# PushAsync is not supported globally on iOS, please use a NavigationPage

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Everything is working fine when I am handling the Tap event of a `ListView` item, but when I use this in a `TabbedPage` it shows the exception please provide a solution to this problem thanks in advance.

> Exception: PushAsync is not supported globally on iOS, please use a NavigationPage.

Here is the Xaml Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NavTest" x:Class="NavTest.NavTestPage" Title="Home">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                <!--<Button Text="Go to " BackgroundColor="Lime" VerticalOptions="Center" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" >
            </Button>-->
                <ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Label Text="{Binding}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

Here's the OnClick Handler:

```
    async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        await  Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
    }
```

Comment: is your ContentPage contained within a NavigationPage?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I changed some formatting to help the question read better.

Comment: I have a tabbed page in which content is a listview and I want to open a new navigation page on tabbed list item tap event ??

Answer (score 20):

This error will come while running in iOS only.

**In App.cs Rootpage(Start page) give like below**

```
 public App()
  {
      MainPage=new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
  }
```

Now, We can use PushAsyn() in Globally

Comment: The same error can happen if you don't use a navigation page even in Android

Comment: And UWP. `'PushAsync is not supported globally on Windows, please use a NavigationPage.'` This answer is The Right One there too, so removing the "running in iOS only" is probably safe.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have some code somewhere similar to this in your `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var tabs = new TabbedPage();    
    tabs.Children.Add(new NavTestPage() { Title = "Tab title" });
    MainPage = tabs;
}
```

Which you should change to:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var tabs = new TabbedPage();
    var page = new NavTestPage() { Title = "Page title" };    
    tabs.Children.Add(new NavigationPage(page) { Title = "Tab title" });

    MainPage = tabs;
}
```

By wrapping in a `NavigationPage` you get the option to push pages onto the navigation stack. A `TabbedPage` on itself is just tabs with only 1 page per tab. This should give you a structure like this:

```
TabbedPage
    NavigationPage
        ContentPage
    NavigationPage
        ContentPage
    NavigationPage
        ContentPage
```

**Update:**
I guess what you're doing is simply changing `ContentPage` to `TabbedPage` in your XAML. That's not how `TabbedPage` works. You should probably read up on how `TabbedPage` actually works in the first place.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page/

In your case you should probably create a new page which has XAML like this:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NavTest"
            x:Class="NavTest.MyTabbedPage">
    <NavigationPage Title="NavTest">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:NavTestPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Set this as the `MainPage` in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new MyTabbedPage();
}
```

Comment: I have a tabbed page in which content is a listview and I want to open a new navigation page on tabbed list item tap event ??

Answer (score 1):

You should put your TabbedPage child page into NavigationPage. The following is code snippets from Xamarin documentation.

**In Xaml:**

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedPageWithNavigationPage;assembly=TabbedPageWithNavigationPage"
        x:Class="TabbedPageWithNavigationPage.MainPage">
    <local:TodayPage />
    <NavigationPage Title="Schedule" Icon="schedule.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:SchedulePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

**Or In Code:**

```
public class MainPageCS : TabbedPage
{
    public MainPageCS ()
    {
        var navigationPage = new NavigationPage (new SchedulePageCS ());
        navigationPage.Icon = "schedule.png";
        navigationPage.Title = "Schedule";

        Children.Add (new TodayPageCS ());
        Children.Add (navigationPage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this error it goes and find the root page and if we are using Master detail page then we have to set the navigation for Detail page only. So following will be the best solution for this.

```
((RootPage)Application.Current.MainPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new SearchPage());
```