# Getting "PushAsync is not supported globally on iOS..." while USING NavigationPage

Tags: ios, f#, xamarin.forms

Ello all, I keep getting the following:

`System.InvalidOperationException` with **"PushAsync is not supported globally on iOS, please use a NavigationPage."**

Even though I am using a `NavigationPage` and am using it properly from what I can tell. My F# skills aren't amazing so I'm definitely thinking I'm doing something wrong here but, surprisingly finding examples of preforming a `Navigation.PushAsync` are hard to come by in F#. I did find this bit of code and have been looking to it for an example of what right looks like.

https://github.com/fsprojects/Tamarin/blob/master/samples/Todo/TodoListMvc.fs

In the example I see this code wrapped in an `async{}`

```
 do! this.Navigation.PushAsync(page = downcast view.Root) |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult |> Async.Ignore
```

so I don't think I'm too far off here. With that said, what am I doing wrong?

### AssemblyVersions

- Xamarin.Forms Version 2.3.5.256-pre6
- FSharp.Core version 4.0.0.1

## Code

```
namespace Eclipsefest

open System
open Xamarin.Forms
open Xamarin.Forms.Xaml

type MenuItem = 
{ Title : string
  TargetType : System.Type }

type MenuPage() = 
inherit ContentPage()
let _ = base.LoadFromXaml(typeof<MenuPage>)
member this.Handle_Tapped(sender : Object, arg : EventArgs) = 
    let navItem = sender :?> TextCell
    async { 
        match navItem.Text with
        | "Information" -> 
            do! this.Navigation.PushAsync(page = new NavigationPage(new InfoPage()))
                |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
                |> Async.Ignore
        | "Events" -> 
            do! this.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new EventsPage()))
                |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
                |> Async.Ignore
        | "BusRoute" -> 
            do! this.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new BusRoutePage()))
                |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
                |> Async.Ignore
        | "Glasses" -> 
            do! this.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new GlassesPage()))
                |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
                |> Async.Ignore
        | "Merch" -> 
            do! this.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new MerchPage()))
                |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
                |> Async.Ignore
        | "Day" -> 
            do! this.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new DayPage()))
                |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
                |> Async.Ignore
        | "About" -> 
            do! this.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new AboutPage()))
                |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
                |> Async.Ignore
        | _ -> 
            do! this.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new EclipsefestPage()))
                |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
                |> Async.Ignore
    }
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

## code update

```
open System
open Xamarin.Forms
open Xamarin.Forms.Xaml

type MenuItem = 
    { Title : string
      TargetType : System.Type }

type MenuPage() = 
    inherit ContentPage()
    let _ = base.LoadFromXaml(typeof<MenuPage>)
    member this.Handle_Tapped(sender : Object, arg : EventArgs) = 
        this.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new EclipsefestPage())) |> ignore
```

I've also tried just this bit and received the same error. I suspected that my issue was with the async portion but it appears to throw the same exception without async as well.

## Code Update 2

```
open System
open Xamarin.Forms
open Xamarin.Forms.Xaml

type MenuItem = 
    { Title : string
      TargetType : System.Type }

type MenuPage() = 
    inherit ContentPage()
    let _ = base.LoadFromXaml(typeof<MenuPage>)
    member this.Handle_Tapped(sender : Object, arg : EventArgs) = 
        let page = new EclipsefestPage()
        let navpage = new NavigationPage(page)
        let result = this.Navigation.PushAsync(navpage)
        result.RunSynchronously()
```

I'm starting to get the feeling that this is a bug. I've verified that the page and the navigation page are instantiated in individual steps prior to calling `Navigation.PushAsync` and am still getting the same exception.

## Error

"PushAsync is not supported globally on iOS, please use a NavigationPage.""

## StackTrace

```
System.InvalidOperationException: PushAsync is not supported globally on iOS, please use a NavigationPage.
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.PushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page root, System.Boolean animated) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:154
  at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.OnPushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean animated) [0x00022] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:190
  at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.PushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page root, System.Boolean animated) [0x00013] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:109
  at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.OnPushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean animated) [0x00022] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:190
  at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.PushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page root, System.Boolean animated) [0x00013] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:109
  at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.OnPushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean animated) [0x00022] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:190
  at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.PushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page root, System.Boolean animated) [0x00013] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:109
  at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.PushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page root) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:102
  at <StartupCode$Eclipsefest>.$MenuPage.xaml+Handle_Tapped@17.Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit unitVar) [0x00090] in /Users/terrancesmith/Projects/Eclipsefest/Eclipsefest/MenuPage.xaml.fs:19
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncBuilderImpl+callA@851[b,a].Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncParams`1[T] args) [0x00047] in <5584acdb904cf4daa7450383dbac8455>:0
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncBuilderImpl.commit[a] (Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncBuilderImpl+Result`1[T] res) [0x00030] in <5584acdb904cf4daa7450383dbac8455>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.CancellationTokenOps.RunSynchronously[a] (System.Threading.CancellationToken token, Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync`1[T] computation, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] timeout) [0x000a3] in <5584acdb904cf4daa7450383dbac8455>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync.RunSynchronously[T] (Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync`1[T] computation, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] timeout, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] cancellationToken) [0x00071] in <5584acdb904cf4daa7450383dbac8455>:0
  at Eclipsefest.MenuPage.Handle_Tapped (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs arg) [0x00008] in /Users/terrancesmith/Projects/Eclipsefest/Eclipsefest/MenuPage.xaml.fs:16
  at Xamarin.Forms.Cell.OnTapped () [0x00008] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Cells\Cell.cs:106
  at Xamarin.Forms.TextCell.OnTapped () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Cells\TextCell.cs:82
  at Xamarin.Forms.TableView+TableSectionModel.OnRowSelected (System.Object item) [0x00007] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TableView.cs:214
  at Xamarin.Forms.TableModel.RowSelected (System.Object item) [0x0001a] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TableModel.cs:65
  at Xamarin.Forms.TableModel.RowSelected (System.Int32 section, System.Int32 row) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TableModel.cs:57
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.TableViewModelRenderer.RowSelected (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\TableViewModelRenderer.cs:85
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
  at Eclipsefest.iOS.Main.main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in <59853c0a6da8a60ca74503830a3c8559>:0
```

Comment: Is this a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109867/pushasync-is-not-supported-globally-on-ios-please-use-a-navigationpage ? (different language obviously)

Comment: Note the bit about me already using "new NavigationPage()" the recommended solution to the existing questions and that that isn't fixing the issue.

Comment: Does the example you found work?  If so, I think your easiest course of action is to slowly convert the working example into the code above and see when it breaks.

Comment: No,  the code is from F# MVC framework (Tamarin) sample app. It is not a 1:1 sort of thing but it was the only thing I found that was using PushAsync in F#.

Comment: There are sample xamarin forms F# examples here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/fsharp/samples/ with a number of `PushAsync` examples like here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples/blob/9b5d456681dee05e6314abdef337091c3a9920b2/Chapter24/StackManipulation/StackManipulation/StackManipulation/PageA.cs#L19 . I think that's your best bet.

Comment: Hmmm I just realized the search result I found was in C#.  You should be able to port to F# though.

Comment: I've looked at all those samples and none of the F# ones are using PushAsync. I've written quite a bit of Xamarin Forms code in C# so I know how to use it in C# so the second link you have there is not particularly helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151165/discussion-between-mydogisbox-and-terrance).

Comment: I totally know how to use Xamarin Forms with C#. I've written quite a bit of it. I am porting and running into issues specifically with NavigationPage.PushAsync not working as expected. If you have some specific bit of info that could contribute to getting that working then it would be helpful.

Comment: BUG FILED:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58603

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer From the folks at Xamarin.

> In the code you showed, you are wrapping the new page you want to push
>   in a NavigationPage. However it's the page you are pushing *from* that
>   needs to be in a navigation page.
>
> The easiest way to do this is to wrap your initial page in a
>   NavigationPage then set it as the MainPage. Then you just push the new
>   pages directly without wrapping them in another NavigationPage because
>   doing so will cause other issues. Check it out:

https://gist.github.com/jimmgarrido/d0b702c1282faa5bb91d0ed14e2d7e1b

```
namespace FForms

open System
open Xamarin.Forms

type TestPage() as this = 
    inherit ContentPage()

    let nextBtn = Button(Text = "Next Page")
    let layout = StackLayout()

    let handler = EventHandler(fun sender args ->
        let newPage = ContentPage(BackgroundColor = Color.Red)
        do this.Navigation.PushAsync(newPage))

    do nextBtn.Clicked.AddHandler handler
    do layout.Children.Add nextBtn
    do base.Content <- layout

type App() = 
    inherit Application(MainPage = NavigationPage(TestPage()))
```

> Hope this helps!

It Did~